# Center of Mass in $N$ dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, centroid

Does Center of Mass make sense in more than three dimensions? In the definition of the Center of Mass we have $dV$. Isn't the volume a three dimensional property? Or it is not and to define the center of mass for, say $4$ dimensions, we just have to calculate a four iterated integral instead of three?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. The integral works in any dimensions just like in 3D. If you have a finite number of points $x_1,\ldots, x_k$, (with unit mass) their center of mass is just $\sum_j x_j/k$ (in any dimension).

Comment: The center of mass is also defined in the 1D and 2D cases, using single and double integrals, and the generalization to nD is rather obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense in any number of dimensions.  You are correct that for a continuous distribution you need one integral per dimension.  Volume is sometimes referred to as $4-$volume in $4$ dimensions.  $dV$ has the dimensionality of the space.